# Help with a Michael Spivak Calculus problem about sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Consider a sequence of closed intervals $I_1 = [a_1, b_1], I_2 = [a_2, b_2]...$ Suppose $a_{n} \le a_{n+1}$ and $b_{n+1} \le b_n$ for all $n$. Prove that there is a point $x$, which is in every $I_n$.

I need some hints to begin. I could simply make the argument $x = a_n$ or $x = b_n$ since it is a closed-interval, but I want something more rigorous?

Comment: If every finite intersection of compact sets is non-empty, then infinite intersection is also non-empty

Comment: "I could simply make the argument $x = a_n$ or $x = b_n$ since it is a closed-interval" - for what $n$? **Hint:** Consider the set $\bigcap \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(I_n\right)$. Can it be empty?

Comment: What does the upside down $U$ mean @GitGud?

Comment: @Rick By definition, $\bigcap \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(I_n\right)=\left\{x\in \mathbb R\colon \forall n\in \mathbb N(x\in I_n)\right\}$.

Comment: @Rick It means intersection of sets: all the elements common to each and all the sets involved. No offence **at all** but I think you should know this *before* you even try to attack this kind of problems. This is very basic set theory.

Comment: @Timbuc, sorry. Gitgud, thanks. How can I prove that it is not empty?

Comment: @Timbuc, but GitGud's definition states it is only for NATURAL numbers?

Comment: @Rick Because that's the way you're indexing the sets. That's all. Observe the sets are **not** of natural numbers but of real ones, but the indexes are from the naturals. Some care is needed here.

Comment: @Timbuc, but why is Git Gud hinting to use intersection of sets?

Comment: @Rick Because that's the mathematical way to denote the set of all the points common to all the sets involved. For example, $\;A\cap B=\{x\;:\;\;x\in A\;\;\text{and also}\;\;x\in B\}\;$ . It's very similar with the intersection of *any* family of sets.

Comment: @Timbuc, I got that. But why do you want to use an intersection of the sets to prove what the question is asking?

Comment: @GitGud I don't really think that is a helpful hint. I mean, your hint basically says that OP should prove the exact thing he does not know how to prove, and then he will know the answer...

Comment: @Rick You must prove the statement "There exists at least one element $x$ such that $x$ is in every $I_n$". This is equivalent to showing that the set $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ is not empty.

Comment: @5xum, thanks. But I dont get this part: Why would you use the UNION or INTERSECTION of different $I_n$'s what good would that do?

Comment: @Rick In my oppinion, no good. Proving that the intersections of $I_n$ is not empty is equally hard as proving that there exists an $x$ that is in every $I_n$. You have not proven that (see my answer for an explanation why).

Comment: @5xum, then how does Gitgud, say that?

Comment: @Rick Gitgud is not wrong. I believe he only misunderstood where your problem is.

Comment: @5xum, Ill comment on yours now.

Answer (score 5):

Observe that $(a_n)$ an increasing sequence bounded above by $b_1$, and $(b_n)$ is a decreasing sequence bounded below by $a_1$. Hence, there are real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a = \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$ and $b = \lim_{n\to \infty} b_n$. Since $a_n < b_n$ for all $n$, $a \le b$. Thus $a_n \le a \le b \le b_n$ for all $n$. Therefore, $a$ (and $b$) belongs to every $I_n$.

Comment: ...and also $\;b\;$ belongs to each $\;I_n\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc yes, I was debating whether or not I should mention that. I'll add that in.

Comment: it is just to make sure one udnerstand the above is **not exactly** the famous Cantor's Intersection Theorem (used, for example, to prove the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem), which also add the condition $\;|I_n|\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;$, which doesn't exist here. Thus, the intersection isn't empty but it can be *more than one point*. +1

Answer (score 1):

The intervals are compact, and any finite intersection is non-empty. Define $J_k=I_k^c$. Then $J_k$ are open. Consider $I_1$. If no points of it belongs to every other $I_k$, then $J_2, J_3, \cdots$ is an open cover of $I_1$. Therefore, there is a finite subcover, let say $J_{k_1}, J_{k_2},\cdots, J_{k_n}$. But then $I_1\cap I_{k_1} \cap I_{k_2} \cdots \cap I_{k_n}=\phi$. A contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Let's get one thing clear: setting $x=a_n$ does not yet prove that there exists some value $x$ which is in every $I_n$. For example, if $$I_n=\left[-\frac{1}{n}, \frac 1n\right],$$ then $a_n=-\frac1n$ and therefore, no matter what the value of $n$ is, the statement

> $a_n$ is in $I_n$ for all values of $n$

is *false*, so your "proof" is not even an informal proof.
 Still, in this example, it is clear that $0$ is in all of the sets $I_n$, so this only shows your proof is wrong, the statement itself.

---

As for hints on how to begin, I advise you to consider the following points:

- The sequence $a_1, a_2, \dots$ is an increasing sequence
- The sequence $a_1, a_2, \dots$ is bounded above by $b_1$ (*why*? What would happen if there existed one such $a_m$ that $a_m > b_1$? Consider the relation between $b_1$ and $b_m$ in that case).
- The sequence $b_1, b_2, \dots$ is a decreasing sequence
- The sequence $b_1, b_2\dots$ is bounded below by $a_1$ (*why*)?

Now, what can you say about the two sequences? Do they converge? If yes, what can you say about their limits?

Comment: Hi. Okay your second bullet point. How do I prove $a_1, a_2....$ is bounded above by $b_1$? $b_{n+1} \le b_1$ is the relation. I need to prove $a_{n+1} \le b_{n+1}$

Comment: @Rick Since $[a_n, b_n]$ is an interval, it means that $a_n\leq b_n$...

Comment: by definition then? Next, $b_{n+1} \ge a_1$ because as you said: $[a_n, b_n]$ so $b_n \ge a_n$

Comment: @Rick Correct, but I don't know why you insist on $n+1$. You can simply say that for each $n$, you know that $b_n \geq a_n$ and $a_n \geq a_1$, meaning that $b_n \geq a_1$.